# Django : pass author post in form instance for creating a chat

Tags: django

I got a question I did not solved. I try to create a chat with the author of the post. But I got an issue when I tried to catch him directly with form instance:

I've created a form with crispy form without field. All field are passed with `form.instance`. I really thank you in advance.

```
#Post detail
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView,FormMixin):
    model = Cuisine
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    form_class = CreateChannelForm
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cuisine_user'] = Cuisine.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.post = self.object
            form.instance.usera = self.request.user
            form.instance.userb = cuisine_user #Here is the error
            form.save()
            return super(PostDetail, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(PostDetail, self).form_invalid(form)
```

I got private space:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    usera = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel_usera")
    userb = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel_userb")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Cuisine,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="channel_post")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('', default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False,unique=True)
```

Here is the model of the post:

```
class Cuisine(models.Model):
    #Remplir manuellement
    title = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='cuisine_user')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nutriscore/')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get userb:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.post = self.object
            form.instance.usera = self.request.user
            form.instance.userb = self.get_object().user #Here is the change
            form.save()
            return super(PostDetail, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(PostDetail, self).form_invalid(form)
```